# HEVC (x265) on Ubuntu 15.04 is not working (even after installing vlc-plugin-libde265)

Tags: 15.04, video, vlc, hevc

I tried installing ppa from *strukturag* with the vlc plugin but every time I play a movie, I get a green layer over the video. On other players, such as smplayer, it only plays the audio without any output.

The video is not corrupted because if I play it with just the plain ffplay command, it looks perfect.

One funny thing is that x265 videos were working on 14.04 but not anymore after upgrading.

Does anybody have a solution/idea for this? I am about to re install from scratch my (k)ubuntu but if possible, I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Facing the same issue here.

Comment: Reproduced the green layer on Trusty. However my file plays correctly using MPlayer.

Comment: After today's update, something went back to normal and now I can played x265 videos at least on vlc, on smplayer I am still getting any video output.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --fix-broken vlc-plugin-libde265 gstreamer0.10-libde265
```

This will ensure that the required packages are installed and not broken.

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I took the liberty to revise your command sequence. It's possible *and* necessary to use `--fix-broken` in the 2nd command because the installation would fail if there were broken packages. This commands implicitly runs `dpkg --configure --all` so the latter was useless at that point.